# Limit a gui program in Linux to only one instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

There are some gui programs where if you select them from the menu, if it is already open, instead of opening a new instance, that window will become foremost. However, there are some programs that will open multiple instances of themselves.

There is a certain program that exhibits the latter behavior but I want it to do the former. How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend replacing the link to the program with a link to a [shell script](http://www.linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial) that [checks if the program is running](http://www.anyexample.com/linux_bsd/bash/check_if_program_is_running_with_bash_shell_script.xml), and if it is, it uses the [window manager's function to bring the program foremost](https://superuser.com/questions/142945/bash-command-to-focus-a-specific-window), and if it isn't, starts it.

Comment: When I do ps ax | grep for the program it shows its status as S when it's running. If I close the program, then it doesn't disappear from the list. Instead it shows its status as S+. What does that mean?

Comment: ^^^ That's a new question. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

I found this thread and implemented it, sharing my version.

I created a executable file `/usr/local/bin/run_once.sh` containing

```
#! /bin/bash
application=$1
if wmctrl -xl | grep "${application}" > /dev/null ; then
    # Already running, raising to front
    wmctrl -x -R "$application"
else
    # Not running: starting
    $@
fi
```

This checks using `wmctrl` if the application you are trying to start already has a window open (some gui programs keep workers without a gui running) instead of using `ps`, using -x to use the `WM_CLASS` instead of the title-bar name.

For each program that I only want one window of I copied the system `.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applications` and changed the `exec` field from `exec=program --arguments` to `exec=/usr/local/bin/run_once.sh program --arguments`

Answer (score 2):

Generally the application source code must be modified.  It is not something done by the operating system.

Comment: Unfortunately this is incorrect as the other answers have shown.

Comment: The other answers to date are but workarounds.  Nothing wrong with that approach except it is not robust or self-contained.  You might want to learn about the contents of `/var/run` and/or `/run`.

Comment: Nonsense. They are perfectly sound.  You can  look for a GUI's title or Window Class and go from there.