# Open a file with eclipse via terminal and focus eclipse window

Tags: linux, ubuntu, eclipse

I am a webdeveloper and my current working tools are:

- Terminal (ssh, tailing logs, grep, git, etc)
- Eclipse (PDT, Javascript, etc)
- Firefox (Developer Toolbar + Firebug)

The problem is that I hate using the eclipse navigation tree. For me it is a lot easier to go to the Terminal and do something like this:

```
$ eclipse /var/www/myproject/long/path/lib/Driver/Sql.php
```

The annoying part is that the eclipse window is not focused after this command.

I have to manually click on the eclipse window (using mouse... :@ grrr)

Anyway to force eclipse to be focused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution: [Bash command to focus a specific window](https://superuser.com/questions/142945/bash-command-to-focus-a-specific-window)

```
#!/bin/sh
export ECLIPSE_HOME="/opt/eclipse"

$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse $*
wmctrl -a Eclipse #This will focus the eclipse window
```