# Cygwin / Windows 10 cli: is there a command that can focus a application/window?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, cygwin

I'm looking for a command that can bring a window into focus. The command has to work in a cygwin terminal, but I imagine this command will be built into Windows, so it's worth saying I'm using Windows 10. I figure this command exists, but I've been unable to find it from googling.

I'm basically asking this but with cygwin instead of Ubuntu: [Bash command to focus a specific window](https://superuser.com/questions/142945/bash-command-to-focus-a-specific-window)

These vbs scripts look promising, but when I execute them in cygwin, they neither error, nor change focus. [CMD command in Windows to switch to an already open application](https://superuser.com/questions/971563/cmd-command-in-windows-to-switch-to-an-already-open-application) It's as if `AppActivate` is a noop.

I'm running `wscript.exe switch.vbs "App Title"` with this script:

```
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
```

It's probably wise to state why I want this functionality: I've made it so that when my tests run from my cygwin commandline, it notifies me the way Windows 10 does with any normal event: with an event bubble. The command I'm using to create that notification (`notifu`) returns different exit codes depending on what happened to the bubble. It'll return an exit code of 3 if I click on it, but whatever window was focused remains in focus. Instead, I want to click on the bubble and focus my cygwin terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I set focus to a Window?

You can use `nircmd win focus ...`.

Example:

```
nircmd win focus title "bash"
```

where `bash` is the title of my Cygwin Terminal window.

**Syntax**

> `nircmd win [action] [find] [window to find] [Additional Parameters]`

There are different ways to specify the `windows to find`:

> ```
> handle: Finds the desired window by specifying the handle of the window in [window to find] parameter.
> id: Finds the desired child window by specifying the id of the child window. Useful only for child windows.
> class: Finds the desired window by specifying the class name of the window in [window to find] parameter.
> title: Finds the desired window by specifying the exact title of the window in [window to find] parameter.
> stitle: Finds the desired window by specifying the first few characters of the window in [window to find] parameter.
> ititle: Finds the desired window by specifying a sequence of characters that exists in the window title.
> alltop: All top windows.
> alltopnodesktop: All top windows, except of desktop and tray windows.
> active: The current active window.
> foreground: The window in foreground.
> desktop: The desktop window
> process:Finds the desired window by specifying process ID (for example: /3412) or process name (for example: firefox.exe).
> ```

Source [Nircmd Win](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/win.html)

Go to [NirCmd - Windows command line tool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to download `nircmd` (download link is at the bottom of the page).

Comment: Just like with `AppActivate`, running this command fails to do anything and there is no error given. Here's the command I wrote: `nircmd win focus ititle "Notepad"` I put Nircmd inside my `~/bin` which is on my path, and I've tried running this in a cygwin terminal (mintty) with and without admin privileges. It doesn't make a difference. It doesn't make a difference if I run it in powershell either.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. What I really wanted was `activate`, not `focus`. I'm not sure if I got the terminology wrong or not here: I've never heard anybody use the phrase "activate the `x` window". I still don't know why the vbs script doesn't work.